# Creating internal DSL in Java

Tags: java, dsl

I have created a class named `VehicleConfig`. It has all sorts of properties such as colour, bhp, type, make, year and so on.

I want to create a DSL for configuring an instance of it. Not all properties should be available to set at all times; it depends on what type of vehicle it is. Cars allows colour selection but not trucks for instance.

How can I do this?  I am looking for a good, thorough explanation of how to write an internal DSL.

Comment: Why DSL? Wouldn't plain old OOP (inheritance for example) suffice?

Comment: It would, but I want to learn something about it too.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be write a `VehicleConfigurationFactory` (Apply your design pattern skill). The main purpose of this factory would be building Different type of `Vehicle`. Every `Vehicle` will have there own definition of there behaviors.

**Factory Design Pattern:** This pattern introduces loose coupling between classes which is the most important principle one should consider and apply while designing the application architecture. Loose coupling can be introduced in application architecture by programming against abstract entities rather than concrete implementations. This not only makes our architecture more flexible but also less fragile.